# How to stop a thread from inside?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this code :-

```
class A {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            
            // Tons of statements.... (Set 1)
            
            
            if(/* We don't meet certain requirements for continuing */) {
                
                // Exit and stop the thread and do not execute any following statements after the if block
                
            }
            
            
            // Tons of statements.... (Set 2)
        }
    };
    
    public void run() {
        t.start();
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.run();
    }
}
```

We start our program with `main` of class B.

Say that `main` in class B finishes all it's instructions while `Thread t` is still executing it's statments in set 1.

Now, there are only two ways for the `t` to stop. Either it reaches end of statement Set 2 (this will result in thread dying out), or the `if` block stops the `Thread t`.

I want to know how can such an if block be implemented ?

If i simply write `join()`, then the `Thread t` doesn't seem to execute furthur command but it stays ALIVE and does not dies out (What i have observed from my experiments).

And `stop()` is depreciated. So what is the proper way to implement the necessary `if` block. What should the body, so that if certain critera do not meet before continuti, we enter the if block and then the code ends the tread without executing any further instruction (below the if block) and then the Thread DIES immediately.

NOW, CLEARLY A SIMPLE & PROPER SOLUTION IS JUST TO PUT ALL THE SET2 INSTRUCTIONS IN `else` BLOCK,

but i'd like to know if there is some other proper way to do this.

I am making a text based game and I create multiple instances of `Class A`. For each instance of A, I have to make such checks at multiple places.

Putting all the further code in `else` blocks will make the code too nested. Indentation looks bad and it feels like this is not the proper approach.

And it will also help me understand threads better. Starting threads is easy, but stopping them always takes a heavy toll on my brain.

Comment: `obj.run();` -- this is not how to start a thread. You would call `obj.start();`, otherwise your code is running in the same thread that the main method is. Also, why extend Thread in the first place? Shouldn't you be implementing Runnable instead?

Comment: `if (condition) { return; }` or `if (!condititon) { /* Set 2 */ }`. Keep in mind that within the `condition` a variable is used that is set by another thread, we need to guarantee inter-htread visibility.

Comment: Please check the second answer in following thread - better way to signal other thread to stop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859681/better-way-to-signal-other-thread-to-stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread terminates when its `run` method completes. The `return` statement terminates a method. Since method `run` returns no value, simply writing `return` in the `if` block will terminate the method and subsequently, the thread.

```java
if(/* We don't meet certain requirements for continuing */) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442427/642706) is correct. Let me add thoughts on avoiding `Thread`.

Since Java 5, we generally no longer address the `Thread` class directly.  Instead use an executor service. Pass a `Runnable` or `Callable` whose code is the task you want performed.

In your main method:

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors. … ;

Runnable runnable = () -> {
     // Tons of statements … 
    if( whatever ) 
    {
        return ;  // Method ends. So then thread ends or is returned to thread pool managed by the executor service.
    }
    // …
    // Method ends. So then thread ends or is returned to thread pool managed by the executor service.
};

executorService.submit( runnable ) ; 
… 
executorService.shutdown() ;
```

In the future, when Project Loom arrives, `ExecutorService` will be `AutoCloseable`. So we can use try-with-resources syntax with the executor service. And the `try` statement will block until all submitted tasks are done (completed or interrupted). The executor service is automatically shutdown at that point.

Comment: It's been long since I have come back to this question to see how stupid I was asking such kind of questions. But it also makes me wanna thank you (which I should have done way too earlier) for this additional tip, that has actually improved the way I handle threads by an exponential factor.